# Border Round Custom Search Button

Tags: css

http://www.pureelysium.com/Pure/Able/

I have a custom search button in the search bar im building, ive placed

```
border: none;
```

On the button to submit, however there appears to be still a small grey border.
however there still seems to be a border still there. Also tried this with img a and a img. Any suggestions?

Thanks
Kirsty

Comment: Are you talking about the input element with the class 'searchbox_submit'?

Comment: Which border are you talking about?

Comment: hi css, yes i am, would it be easier to put searchbox_submit img a  {border: none;}

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add `outline: 0` to your css, both for `.searchbox_submit` and for `.searchbox_submit:focus`

Answer (score 0):

What if you put `style="border-style:none;"` inside your input element?  I believe that should override any other border related styles for that element.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there's a bug in how some browsers are handling image typed submit buttons.  Your best bet might be to use a regular submit button, and use something like `background: url(...);` as your image.  Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ytz7L/